# Corrupt forms, not displaying in "startup form"?

Tags: vb.net, forms, corrupt

In properites>Application>"Startup form" combobox, in my VS VB.NET project, I see only 2 forms listed, while my application has 6 forms. Does this mean something is corrupt?

I tried to make a new project, then copy only the old vb files into this new project. But still only those two (of 6) forms show up in the "Startup form" combo box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's pretty odd.  This list is almost certainly filled from the project file, the `<SubType>` element should be significant.  But you eliminated that possibility by recreating the project file from scratch.  I can't see how a property on a form would make it disappear from the list.

One thing you could try is editing the My Project\Application.myapp file with Notepad.  Copy the solution first and make sure it isn't loaded in VS.  Change the `<MainForm>` element to one of the forms that isn't listed.  Load the project and see what is shown in the project property page and if anything breaks when you compile it.